# create tfrecord from labelme json file

Tags: python, json, tensorflow, object-detection, tfrecord

I want to create an object detection neural network, from some special item with special shape with **limited** **relativly small** image datasets.For this i used **labelme** I think polygonal labeling would perform better then normal boxing labeling because of the shape of the object.
I want to use of one the pretrained model from coco Tensorflow detection models, but im **struggling** to **create tfrecord file** from json files.As you can see below it countain both polygon and circle shape_type. Thank for your help in advance. **If you know how to convert it to tfrecord or some alternative labeling program that would work better for my problem pls let me know i will just relabel my imageses if its solve my problem.** json file For example:

```
    {
  "version": "3.5.0",
  "flags": {},
  "shapes": [
    {
      "label": "polygon",
      "line_color": null,
      "fill_color": null,
      "points": [
        [
          447,
          110
        ],
        [
          491,
          63
        ],
        [
          531,
          47
        ],
        [
          559,
          79
        ],
        [
          544,
          121
        ],
        [
          532,
          128
        ],
        [
          536,
          139
        ],
        [
          516,
          148
        ],
        [
          497,
          174
        ]
      ],
      "shape_type": "polygon"
    },
    {
      "label": "circle",
      "line_color": null,
      "fill_color": null,
      "points": [
        [
          403,
          317
        ],
        [
          377,
          262
        ]
      ],
      "shape_type": "circle"
    }
  ],
  "lineColor": [
    0,
    255,
    0,
    128
  ],
  "fillColor": [
    255,
    0,
    0,
    128
  ],
  "imagePath": "teszt.jpg",
  imageData ...(long data)
```

Comment: Do you have any progress on this? i'm also wondering. if you made progress can you share as an answer

Answer (score 3):

From the looks of JSON file i believe you are doing instance segmentation.
You could use scripts provided in the `labelme` examples directory.

[Instance Segmentation folder](https://github.com/wkentaro/labelme/tree/master/examples/instance_segmentation) has two scripts `labelme2coco.py` and `labelme2voc.py`

So you can convert `labelme` JSONs to COCO format or VOC format and use them to build TFRecords

[tensorflow models repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/dataset_tools) has a bunch of scripts to help you do this